# How does open() work with and without `with`?

Tags: python

I'd like to write a function similar to `open`. I'd like to be able to call it with `with`, but also without `with`.

When I use `contextlib.contextmanager`, it makes my function work fine with `with`:

```
@contextmanager
def versioned(file_path, mode):
    version = calculate_version(file_path, mode)
    versioned_file = open(file_path, mode)
    yield versioned_file
    versioned_file.close()
```

So, I use it like this:

```
with versioned('file.txt', 'r') as versioned_file:
    versioned_file.write(...)
```

How do I use it without `with`:

```
versioned_file = versioned('file.txt', 'r')
versioned_file.write(...)
versioned_file.close()
```

It complains:

```
AttributeError: 'GeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `def versioned(file_path, mode):\n    def write(...);` ?

Comment: You need to make a `Versioned` context manager `class` with a `write()` method. `@contextmanager` is decorator that wraps a function so it can be used as a contextmanagers, but it's still a function and thus cannot have methods like `class` instance does.

Comment: @martineau Not exactly true. Functions are just objects that happen to have a `__call__` method. So I can easily provide an object that has this one (and as such *is* a function) but also provides other methods.

Comment: @martineau They can! `def foo(): pass; def bar(): print "Hello World"; foo.bar=bar; foo.bar()`

Comment: @Dunno: That doesn't make a `foo.bar()` or `foo().bar()` method.

Comment: @martineau it does make a `foo.bar()` method, at least on my 2.7 python interpreter. Even better, you can create instance `foo2=foo` and `foo2.bar()` still works

Comment: @Dunno: `foo.bar()` isn't a method. For one thing it doesn't receive a `self` argument. `bar` is just a function attribute that happens to be callable.

Comment: @martineau oh well, but close to it!

Comment: @poke: If that's all a function is, why didn't you just define a function with a `write()` method in your answer?

Comment: @martineau a function is an object, an instance of the class function, you can add properties to it, function and even methods. Try it! define a method **m** and do a dir(m), or even better, try m.__call__()

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to be able to have open a versioned file for reading or writing. It will use the latest version for reading, or the next version for writing. I want to encapsulate that.

Comment: @martineau Not sure what you mean, but that still wouldn’t provide the context functions.

Comment: @poke: I meant write a function with a `write()` method and use `@contextmanager` on the function.

Comment: @martineau As I explained in my answer, the object returned from a `@contextmanager`-decorated function is a special generator. It is not the object we yield from the function, and as such not really useable outside of a `with`-context. So no, it simply doesn’t work with `@contextmanager`.

Comment: @poke: Precisely, which is why I suggested making a class with a `write()` method in my initial comment -- which is exactly what you did in your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this:

```
@contextmanager
def versioned(file_path, mode):
    # some setup code
    yield versioned_file
    # some teardown code
```

Your basic problem of course is that what you `yield` from the context manager comes out of the `with` statement via `as`, but is not the object returned by your function. You want a function that returns something that behaves like the object `open()` returns. That is to say, a context manager object that yields itself.

Whether you can do that depends what you can do with the type of `versioned_file`. If you can't change it then you're basically out of luck. If you can change it then you need to implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions as specified in [PEP 343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

In your example code, though, *it already has it*, and your teardown code is the same as what it does itself on context exit already. So don't bother with contextlib at all, just return the result of `open()`.

For other examples where you do need `__enter__` and `__exit__`, if you like the contextlib style (and who doesn't?) you can bridge the two things. Write a function `context` that's decorated with `@contextmanager` and yields `self`. Then implement:

```
def __enter__(self):
    self.context = context() # if context() is a method use a different name!
    return self.context.__enter__()
def __exit__(self, *args):
    return self.context.__exit__(*args)
```

It's basically up to you whether you find this better or worse than separating out the setup code into `__enter__` and the teardown code into `__exit__`. I generally find it better.

Comment: Yes, @SamyArous spotted this, too. I got caught up in thinking about `contextlib`, and didn't realise I didn't need it at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that [`contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) only provides exactly that; a context manager to be used in the `with` statement. Calling the function does *not* return the file object, but a special context generator which provides the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions. If you want both the `with` statement and “normal” assignments to work, then you will have to have some object as the return value from your function that is fully usable *and* also provides the context functions.

You can do this pretty easily by creating your own type, and manually providing the context functions:

```
class MyOpener:
    def __init__ (self, filename):
        print('Opening {}'.format(filename))
    def close (self):
        print('Closing file.')
    def write (self, text):
        print('Writing "{}"'.format(text))
    def __enter__ (self):
        return self
    def __exit__ (self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.close()
```

```
>>> f = MyOpener('file')
Opening file
>>> f.write('foo')
Writing "foo"
>>> f.close()
Closing file.

>>> with MyOpener('file') as f:
        f.write('foo')

Opening file
Writing "foo"
Closing file.
```

Comment: I think @SamyArous has it below (hopefully he will rise). I can just use `open`'s context manager to handle it. Your answer does answer the general case, and Sammy's sees my specific needs, and simplifies, so you are both correct.

Answer (score 4):

Do you really need to use contextlib.contextmanager? 
If you have a custom stream you would want to use Poke's solution.

But since you are just returning a file object, why go through all the hassle:

```
def versioned(file_path, mode):
    version = calculate_version(file_path, mode)
    return open(file_path, mode)


with versioned('test.conf', 'r') as stream:
   print stream.read()

f = versioned('test.conf', 'r')
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Both will work perfectly fine :)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I want. I was getting blinded by the need to manage the context. I can let `open`'s context manager do that.

Comment: This `versioned` function will cause the file to be closed automatically when used in a `with`, but will be unable to do any post-processing before that occurs -- which would be possible, even if not used in the OP's code, via the `@contextmanager` decorator.

Comment: @martineau then as I said, he should simply use poke's solution which is more flexible.